# Crear contenido con json y ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Tengo unas dudas y problemas.

Mi código es el siguiente.

**en html**

```
<div id="summary"></div>
```

**en js**

```
function callurl() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      JsonpCallback(msg);
    },
    error: function() {
      ErrorFunction();
    }
  });
}

function JsonpCallback(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    $('#summary').append('<b>Post:</b> ' + json[i].id + '<br />');
    $('#summary').append('<b>Título:</b> ' + json[i].title + '<br />');
    $('#summary').append('<b>Descripción:</b> ' + json[i].body + '<br />');
    $('#summary').append('<hr />');
  }
}

callurl();
```

Necesito, la forma de crear una lista.

Ejemplo.

**Post:** 1

**Título:** sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit

***`Boton Abrir contenido.`***

Al hacer click se abra el contenido de ese post.

**Contenido:** uia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto.

Quiero llegar a una pequeña app, donde se muestre un feed de post con el título y al darle click me abra el contenido de ese post.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede mejorar pero creo que te da una idea de cómo hacerlo utilizando solo JQuery y Ajax:

```js
function callurl() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      JsonpCallback(msg);
    },
    error: function() {
      ErrorFunction();
    }
  });
}

function JsonpCallback(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    $('#summary').append('<b>Post:</b> ' + json[i].id + '<br />');
    $('#summary').append('<b>Título:</b> ' + json[i].title + '<br />');
    $('#summary').append('<span id="description_' + i + '"><b>Descripción:</b> ' + json[i].body + '<br /></span>');
    $('#summary').append('<button id="_' + i + '">Mostrar</button>');
    $('#summary').append('<hr />');
    $('#description_' + i).hide();
    $('#_' + i).on('click', function(event) {
     var id = event.currentTarget.id;
     $('#description' + id).show()
    })
  }
}

callurl();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="summary"></div>
```

Comment: Muy bueno! Gracias @potray , solo una cosa, que pasa si quiero que todo se abra con un boton? :)

Comment: @JuanDavid Utilizando como referencia la solución que te he dado, tendrías que hacer que ese botón llame a una función que, en un bucle, vaya haciendo $('#description_' + i).show().

Comment: una ayuda mas, si quiero agregar una variable en la llamada del ajax
url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts&$key&$otherkey',

y añadir el valor de esa variable en 
var $key = sssss
 como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: @JuanDavid no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta original, pero lo que quieres hacer no es una simple concatenación de cadenas?

Comment: @JuanDavid para hacer cosas más complejas te puedo recomendar que estudies librerías como Angular (https://angularjs.org/) o React (https://facebook.github.io/react/).